# kotlin gradle dsl problem : Type mismatch: inferred type is String but URI! was expected

Tags: android, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I am trying to convert `Gradle's Groovy DSL` to Kotlin DSL

Gradle Groovy Code is :

```
 repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo.tools.telstra.com/repository/maven-public"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
```

I am trying this to convert into `Kotlin DSL`, like below:

```
 repositories {
        maven { url  = ("https://repo.tools.telstra.com/repository/maven-public") }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url =  ('https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/') }
    }
```

With that I am getting error as:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is String but URI! was expected

How can I setup URI here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment I am using Gradle 6.9,  there we have to write it like below:

```
repositories {
    maven(url = uri("https://repo.tools.telstra.com/repository/maven-public"))
    mavenCentral()
    maven( url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent to Groovy DSL's

```
maven {
    url "https://repo.tools.telstra.com/repository/maven-public"
}
```

In Kotlin DSL is:

```kotlin
maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks @ksviety - I added some more explanation to satisfy the the community admin, please take a look for future guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This is already solved here [How to add a maven repository by url using kotlinscript DSL (build.gradle.kts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242437/how-to-add-a-maven-repository-by-url-using-kotlinscript-dsl-build-gradle-kts).

```
repositories {
        maven { url  = ("https://repo.tools.telstra.com/repository/maven-public") }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url =  ('https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/') }
    }
```

In `Kotlin DSL` would be

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven ( url = "https://repo.tools.telstra.com/repository/maven-public" )
    maven ( url = "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" )

}
```